# Moment keep coming up on validation form

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd

I am working on a date picker and as simple as it seems, the validation keeps return the moment object regardless. I'll jump straight to the code:

```
const DATE_VALIDATION_RULE = {
  validator(_, value) {

    console.log(value, "Here"); // This keeps returning the moment object

    if (!value) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
    if (!isDefined(parseDate(value))) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Must be valid date of form DD/MM/YYYY'));
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
  },
};

export interface DateInputFormItemProps {
  value?: (string | undefined);
  label?: string;
  name: string | (string | number)[];
  onChange?: (value: (string)) => void;
  rules?: Rule[];
  dependencies?: (string | (string | number)[])[];
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export const DateInputFormItem = ({
  value,
  label,
  name,
  onChange,
  rules = [],
  dependencies,
  disabled,
}: DateInputFormItemProps) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<string | undefined>(value);

  const dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

  useEffect(() => {
    setDate(value);
  }, [value]);

  const handleOnChange = (value, dateString) => {
    setDate(dateString);
    console.log('Formatted Selected Time: ', dateString, date);
    onChange?.(dateString);

  }

  return (
    <Form.Item
      label={label}
      name={name}
      rules={[DATE_VALIDATION_RULE, ...rules]}
      dependencies={dependencies}
    >
      <DatePicker
        format={dateFormat}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        disabled={disabled}
      />
    </Form.Item>
  );
};
```

I recently did a range picker, which has exactly the same code, but in the range case, the validation gets the dates as expected, but this one keeps returning the moment object. Thanks

Comment: If you just simply console the `value`, you will see, it will console the moment object. You don't need to again pass to the moment constructor. I also check the RangePicker, in validator function, the value is an array of moment object. You need to parse the moment value to date before applying the checks.

Comment: That's the problem, i passes the moment object, but I want it to pass just the date as it does in rangePicker

Comment: You can parse the date as `let date = moment(value).format(dateFormat)`.  For formatting, you can follow the documentation `https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/`

Comment: that works, although I don't understand why is necessary here and not in the range one

Comment: I also checked the rangepicker, the value is an array of moment object. I tested both datepicker and rangepicker using antd@4.20.3. Now i'm not sure which version you are using or how you coded the rangepicker.

Comment: Is literally the same code, but changing it for range picker. I am getting a date.clone is not a function error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244671/discussion-between-nouman-rafique-and-mario-garcia).